# Вытащить динамичную фразу из большой строки

Tags: python

В общем, у меня есть огромная строка, из которой необходимо вытащить в данном случае "Ливерпуль - Бавария". Эта фраза меняется каждый раз. Многоточия означают, что там еще куча всего перед и после. Думал насчет регулярок, но я в них полный ноль.

```
`.......initialEvents: {"enabled":true,"totalCount":8,"events":[{"id":281474982553600,"name":"Ливерпуль - Бавария","competitors":[{"id":281474976720725,"name":"Ливерпуль","homeAway":"HOME","type":"TEAM",........`
```

Пс. Этот словарь - не словарь и не json, это всё строка. И там еще другой разнообразный текст.

Comment: Ну это JSON, наверняка? Покажите всю?

Comment: @Andrey нет, там не json, там именно огромный текст, среди которого пародия на json, но он как бы строка

Comment: А откуда у вас такой результат, из какого-то API?

Comment: @Andrey парсил очень плохой сайт... либо я плохой программист

Comment: Нужен чёткий алгоритм определения извлекаемой строки. Значение первого `name` после `events`?

Comment: @Andrey да, по сути нужно то, что между "name":" и ","competitors"

Comment: @Adrian конструкция "initialEvents: {}" одна на всю строку?

Comment: @Andrey да, но перед и после нее посторонний текст

Comment: @Adrian предложил решение. Но если вы покажете ваш код или страницу, с которой вытягиваете данные, то возможно найдется способ нормально получить нужные данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Красивое решение с регулярными выражениями напишет кто-нибудь другой. Можно вытащить нужную вам часть сплитами. С другими строками будет работать в том случае, если ключи  в `inititalEvents` находятся в той же последовательности.

```
s = '.......initialEvents: {"enabled":true,"totalCount":8,"events":[{"id":281474982553600,"name":"Ливерпуль - Бавария","competitors":[{"id":281474976720725,"name":"Ливерпуль","homeAway":"HOME","type":"TEAM",........'

result = (s.split('initialEvents: {')[1]
           .split('"name":"')[1]
           .split('","competitors"')[0])

print(result)
# Ливерпуль - Бавария
```